# How to get healthier an old kalanchoe plant?

Tags: kalanchoe

I have recently brought this kalanchoe plant from work. Previously it was by the window and would flower a couple of times a year. It has been less vital at my place. I learned that it needs a different placement to increase the sunlight (new placement in photos). It has leggy stems and leaves at the ends of the stems. Anything else I can do to improve its health? Is it worth saving or better to trim and replant the trimmings?

Thank you.[image: nna[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi6zx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I've had kalanchoe plants get leggy in the past, and I've always trimmed off the ends and either rooted them in water or planted them in well-watered soil. If you trim the ends, your original plant will probably continue to grow as well, perhaps with a more compact shape.

Here are some loose suggestions about where to cut the stems. It's really up to you. I like to trim them so that the trimmings have a few inches of leafless area that will be easy to plant or root in a water-filled jar. Similarly, if you want to keep the original plant, I would trim the original stems to be a few inches long, so that they'll be a minor part of the plant when leaves start growing from them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How close to the base would you trip on this plant?

Comment: I edited my response to show how I might trim the plant. There's a lot of leeway.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!